# How to work with multiple .net projects on os x and vs code

Tags: mono, projects-and-solutions, visual-studio-code, dnx

I am trying to create a typical solution/project layout using vs code. I created the various libraries using `yo aspnet`, but I don't know how to reference projects in vs code. Do I use a single project.json at the root? How does it know what the startup project and entry point are? Also, is there a way to get intellisense on the namespacing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't use Visual Studio (the full version), then you don't need a solution or xproj files. You just use folders and `project.json` files to mark your projects then each project can add a reference to another one in the `dependencies` section of the project file, like in this example:

https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/1b302daf1c9bf7e723a26f5507f033c3e313e106/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Ini/project.json#L20-L23

Edit (summary of the comments):

- To reference projects in other folders, add them to the `global.json` file
- To get intellisense in VS code, you must select a project (there's a drop down in the lower right corner of the window)

Comment: Yes, but I haven't found an example where my dependency is in a neighboring folder like a typical solution. And once I added, I'm unsure of how to make this compile.

Comment: Oh, no problem. That's achieved using `global.json`. You add the folders that contain sources to that file. Here's an example: https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/dev/global.json The discovery algorithm looks for project references in the folder where the current project is and any folder in `global.json`

Comment: Ok, I noticed that example's project.json has `"compile": [ "../../shared/**/*.cs" ]`. I take it, I'm supposed to glob in any local project dependencies so that my project will compile?

Comment: Nope. If you include something in `compile` those files will be compiled in your project's assembly. If you reference a package in the project.json file, then if dnx finds the sources for it, it will use them and compile a project reference, otherwise it will try to find the package (nupkg)

Comment: Ah, I think I get it. "global.json" was the tip I needed. I found http://gavindraper.com/2015/05/20/asp-net-5-multiple-projects-and-global-json/, which explains a bit more on referencing local projects.

Comment: What about intellisense? What do most people use? Xamarin Studio?

Comment: VS Code provides intellisense both in cs files and `project.json`

Comment: It seems intellisense only works once I have already typed the word somewhere else in that same file. It doesn't seem to look through all files in my working directory. Also, before vs code did most people use xamarin studio?

Comment: You should have full intellisense, just like in the full VS. Did you select a project (bottom right corner)?

Comment: AHA! Maybe you should update your answer to include all of these bits, and we should move this to community wiki.