# How can Visual Studio Code on OSX import sln/csproj and run?

Tags: c#, asp.net, macos, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code seems like it would be a very nice tool, but right out of the gate it seemingly cannot read any configuration that would make it part of the Visual Studio family.  How can I import my sln/csproj files so that Code knows how to understand them?

Comment: To partially answer my own question, looks like some insight here: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/Converting-a-csproj-from-package.config-to-project.json

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Visual Studio Code isn't designed to work with sln/csproj files unfortunately (or fortunately depending on how you look at it).

In order to use your project created in Windows create a .NET Core application and use 'Portable Class Libraries' instead of standard class libraries then Open Folder in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Further reading - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36274642/how-to-work-with-multiple-net-projects-on-os-x-and-vs-code

Answer (score 0):

You can open it, using vscode-solution-explorer [link for more info](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fernandoescolar.vscode-solution-explorer)
(P.s. Not everything works as smoothly as we would like, but it's still better than nothing)