# How to debug not Core ASP.NET MVC5 running on IIS Express using Visual Studio Code?

Tags: debugging, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-express, visual-studio-code

I have this project, ASP.NET MVC5 WebApi, it was created using Visual Studio 2015.

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Happens I'm temporarily unable to use VS2015 to work, so I'm working in Visual Studio Code by now.

I was able to configure almost everything I need to work, OmniSharp is working fine, so I have intellisense, I'm able to build the solution with msbuild and run IIS Express to test the work. Everything I need but **debug**. =/

I'm actually able to attach vscode to iisexpress instance, but it keeps the breakpoints in gray saying that no symbols were loaded. I tried to use the *symbolPath* in the attach configuration, had no success.

All the debug console says:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
You may only use the Microsoft .NET Core Debugger (clrdbg) with Visual Studio
Code, Visual Studio or Visual Studio for Mac software to help you develop and
test your applications.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Maybe the clrdbg just cant target .NET 4.5.2?
Maybe they need more information on how to load the symbols?
Maybe I am missing a directive on iisexpress command line?

Any help will be most appreciated. Thanks. :)

Here is how I build: (*Both of them works fine*)

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "cmd",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["/c"],
    "showOutput": "always",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build",
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "suppressTaskName": true,
            "args": [
                "dotnet build",
                "${workspaceRoot}\\MyWebApi.sln"
            ],
            "showOutput": "always",
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "taskName": "build with msbuild",
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "suppressTaskName": true,
            "args": [
                "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\14.0\\Bin\\MSBuild.exe",
                "${workspaceRoot}\\MyWebApi.sln",
                "/p:Configuration=Debug;GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/t:Rebuild",
                "/m",
                "/v:m",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true"
            ],
            "showOutput": "always",
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is how I run iisexpress:

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" /config:".\.vs\config\applicationhost.config" /site:MyWebApi /apppool:Clr4IntegratedAppPool /trace:e
```

Here how I attach:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to IIS Express",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processName": "iisexpress"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: According to [vscode documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp) this is not possible, quote: "Note: VS Code does not support debugging applications running on the Desktop .NET Framework."

Comment: Yeah, found something about it a couple hours latter.
Some reading: 
https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/813
https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/283
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37062818/how-can-visual-studio-code-on-osx-import-sln-csproj-and-run

I will come back and answer the question as soon as vscode support it.
Thanks @mark!

Answer (score 0):

Note that it's now possible to debug C# code in Visual Studio Code using the `C# for Visual Studio Code` extension by OmniSharp.  From what I've seen so far the experience is actually really good:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/03/10/experimental-net-core-debugging-in-vs-code/

Answer (score 0):

With OmniSharp now supporting debugging with the C# extension, I was able to debug c# with IIS.

My setup is very similar to yours, however, in your `launch.json` change the type line from `"type": "coreclr"` to `"type": "clr"`.  This should let you debug .NET framework projects whether they are using IIS or not.